# Branches of the cubic function

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a question from Palka.

> Exhibit all three branches of the cube root function in the domain $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$

First let $r=|z|^{1/3}$ and $\Theta=Arg\, z$ we have $$re^{i\left(\frac{\Theta+2\pi K}{3}\right)}$$ which becomes $re^{i\Theta/3}$, $re^{i\Theta/3}e^{2\pi/3}$, and $re^{\Theta/3}e^{4\pi/3}.$

I'm not sure if I'm approaching us the right way.  I'm kind of confused about what the question is asking for.

Comment: You are correct. Since $\log$ has $\omega$ branches in that domain, and for each one $z\mapsto e^{\frac{1}{3}\log z}$ is a branch of cubic root. 'Almost all' of these turn out to be the same (branches of $\log$ differ by an integer multiple of $2\pi i$), leaving only these possibilities.

Comment: So are the three branches, to put it colloquially, look like a Pac-Man with an open mouth facing to the left.

Comment: The constants by which you multiply the principle branch do, yes. The branches themselves are complex functions, and my imagination breaks in 4 dimensions ;)

Comment: Perhaps I'm confusing the question then.  I listed those three things and then I drew a Pac-Man looking thing.

Comment: What you have are the three mappings (for $-\pi<\theta<\pi$): (a) $re^{i\theta}\mapsto\sqrt[3]{r}e^{i\frac{\theta}{3}}$, (b) $re^{i\theta}\mapsto\sqrt[3]{r}e^{i\frac{\theta}{3} + \frac{2\pi i}{3}}$ and (c) $re^{i\theta}\mapsto\sqrt[3]{r}e^{i\frac{\theta}{3} + \frac{4\pi i}{3}}$.